# Is there a difference between .values() in linux verus windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I've written some code on my windows computer, and transferred it over to a linux system. They both have python3 and should have the same libraries. However, while my script works fine in windows, I get an error message on linux.

This is the part of the code causing issues:

```
Normalized=(Combined/Dilutions.values)
#where 
print(Combined)
   Column_4  Column_4  Column_4  Column_4  Column_4  Column_4
2     50034     50034     32355     21058     10457         0
3     38230     38230     31054     18963     11770         0
4     34503     34503     22208     14216      5492         0
5     34219     34219     22975     11450      4148         0
6     37442     37442     25319     16206      7369         0
7     32144     32144     21293     14307      5594         0
8     28053     28053     19972     10767      4448      2634
9     30395     30395     22899     10458      4967         0

#and 
print (Dilution)
          0         1        2        3        4      5
0  103000.0  103000.0  95000.0  79600.0  78100.0  74562
```

Granted, while these are different sizes, I am able to divide the values in dilution over every row in Combined. It appears I am unable to do so in linux though, running this command gives me this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blue.py", line 61, in <module>
    Normalized=(Combined/Dilutions.values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 1257, in f
    other = _align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 1180, in _align_method_FRAME
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (8, 6): given (1, 6)
```

Is there a package I'm missing in linux that is there in windows? Otherwise I don't know why it would work on one OS but not another.

Comment: You probably have an older pandas version on Linux, [see](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#dataframe-arithmetic-operations-broadcasting-changes)

Comment: No wonder I was confused by your code! Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Also, you probably shouldn’t be using `.values` anyway. Are you using virtual environments? What is your program meant to do, you might be able to ditch Pandas for this entirely.

Comment: For simplicity sake I'll just link you where my code is, and my description of it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234458/first-time-writing-a-script-any-advice-would-be-appreciated/234459#234459   but in short, this part of the code is normalizing my datatable values by dividing the values in each row of my datatable by the values of dilution. I use pandas to form the datatable (so I can't ditch it entirely). Its more obvious why when you see the full code in the link, I only posted the portion of the error here because given those inputs, that single line should work.

Comment: @samman Alright, I'll take a look at that other question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pip freeze` on each to confirm which packages and versions are installed on each system. For more control, you can install Anaconda on both Windows and Linux, then you can manage specific versions of each package... including Python itself.

When you are working with dataframes (or Numpy arrays) of different sizes, shouldn't you be broadcasting to cover the difference in sizes?

Comment: It apperars that might be the issue. The linux system is using pandas 0.22, whereas the windows is using 0.25. 

As for the 2nd question, .values seems to compensate for the size difference.